# Getting selected rows in QListWidget

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qlistwidget

I have a `Qlistwidget` in which I can select multiple items. I can get a list with all the selected items in the listwidget but can not find a way to get a list of the corresponding rows. To get a list of the selected items in the listwidget I used the following code:

```
print [str(x.text()) for x in self.listWidget.selectedItems()]
```

To retrieve the rows I am looking for something like:

```
a = self.listWidget.selectedIndexes()
print a
```

But this does not work. I have also tried some code which resulted in outputs like this, which is not very useful:

```
<PyQt4.QtGui.QListWidgetItem object at 0x0000000013048B88>
<PyQt4.QtCore.QModelIndex object at 0x0000000014FBA7B8>
```

Comment: By "indices" do you mean row ? Index and row numbers are not the same thing in Qt. If you mean row, I suggest editing your question (including title).

Comment: I guess i needed row yeah, i will change it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The weird output is because you are getting objects of type `QModelIndex` or `QListWidgetItem`. The `QModelIndex` object has a method to get its row, so you can use:

```py
[x.row() for x in self.listWidget.selectedIndexes()]
```

To get a list of all selected indices.

Answer (score 7):

selectedIndexes and QModelIndex should be all you need.

```
liwidg = QtGui.QListWidget()
liwidg.show()
liwidg.setSelectionMode( QtGui.QAbstractItemView.SelectionMode.ExtendedSelection)
liwidg.addItems(["a", "b", "c", "d"])
liwidg.selectedIndexes()
```

When selected 'a', 'b', and 'c' liwidg.selectedIndexes() Gives:

```
[<PySide.QtCore.QModelIndex(0,0,0xb266478,QListModel(0xb0e6400) )   at 0x0C86EB20>,
 <PySide.QtCore.QModelIndex(1,0,0xb266518,QListModel(0xb0e6400) )   at 0x0C861D78>,
 <PySide.QtCore.QModelIndex(2,0,0xb2843c8,QListModel(0xb0e6400) )   at 0x0C869AF8>]
```

You can use the QModelIndex to get whatever information you need.

```
sel0 = liwidg.selectedIndexes()[0]
# <PySide.QtCore.QModelIndex(0,0,0xb266478,QListModel(0xb0e6400) )   at 0x0C85B530>

print(sel0.data())
print(sel0.row())
print(sel0.column())
```

Prints:

```
'a'
0
0
```

This works for me.

Comment: Thank you, this is what i needed